# How to get the validity of a component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What I'm trying to do is to get the validity of the `e.target` thru `aria-invalid` without using onBlur (It's a must cant be change) and only trigger the onChange to get the `e.target`. I already used the `setInvalid({ ...invalid, [e.target.name]: e.target.validity.valid })`, but when `onBlur` is triggered, it backs to default (true).

Is there any way to get the validity of the component and be use to `setInvalid({ ...invalid, [e.target.name]:` **???** `})`?

*The validation comes from the `TextField` component's `onBlur` itself and has separate code, so passing `onBlur` props (like `onChange`) to use in `CustomForm` can't be done.

**CustomForm Code**

```
   import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
    
    export const CustomForm = (initialState = {}, onSubmit) => {
      const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState)
      const [invalid, setInvalid] = useState({})
    
      const handleChange = (e: any) => {
        const validate = e.target.getAttribute('aria-invalid')
        setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
        setInvalid({ ...invalid, [e.target.name]: validate })
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log(invalid)
      }, [invalid])
    
      const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        onSubmit?.({ values, invalid })
      }
    
      return { values, handleChange, handleSubmit }
    }
```

**CustomForm as component**

```
const { values, handleChange, handleSubmit } = CustomForm(
  {
    password: "",
  },
  (values) => alert(JSON.stringify(values))
);

    const { password } = values;
    
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
          value={password}
          type="password"
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
          texts={{
            name: "password",
            field: "Password",
          }}
          isRequired
          isRequiredMark
          minLength={8}
        />
    
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </form>
    );
```

Comment: Is `CustomForm` supposed to be a custom React hook? If so, it should be properly named, i.e. something like `useCustomForm`. What validity are you referring to? Have you tried using proper functional state updates since it appears your next state *depends* on previous state?

Comment: I would check out 'react hook form' (https://react-hook-form.com/). This is not an answer to your question, but it can be a solution to your problem.